# Games in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, games

First, I download small games, this game is only 2D and can only move left and right, but very lag. 
In windows xp, i can play gta 3 and vice city in full speed, CS 1.6 (medium quality) smoothly, NFS Underground 2 little lag.

So, this is because the OS or because of a game that I downloaded? 
If I download another game, whether it will lag too?

I have a netbook with Intel Atom N280 and 1GB of RAM.

**edit**
I can play Final Fantasy VII using from software center PCSX smoothly in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can install zram-config on your netbook to improve performance. Just bring up the terminal and type the following:

`$ sudo apt-get update`
`$ sudo apt-get install zram-config`

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Ubuntu 32-bit or 64-bit? Cause using 64-bit version will experience some performance issues with less then 2GB of ram.

Comment: I use 32-bit. probably my graphics driver that caused this. How do I check the driver installed?